# what will happen internally when you call getSystemService(WIFI_SERVICE) in android?

Tags: android, android-wifi, android-framework

After this `getSystemService(WIFI_SERVICE)`  called , is the `WifiManager` `Constructor` called from `frameworks/base/wifi/java/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.java` class

The Constructor is :

```
public WifiManager(IWifiManager service, Handler handler) {
    mService = service;
    mHandler = handler;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This class provides the primary API for managing all aspects of Wi-Fi connectivity. Get an instance of this class by calling Context.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE). It deals with several categories of items:

The list of configured networks. The list can be viewed and updated, and attributes of individual entries can be modified.

The currently active Wi-Fi network, if any. Connectivity can be established or torn down, and dynamic information about the state of the network can be queried.

Results of access point scans, containing enough information to make decisions about what access point to connect to.

It defines the names of various Intent actions that are broadcast upon any sort of change in Wi-Fi state.

This is the API to use when performing Wi-Fi specific operations. To perform operations that pertain to network connectivity at an abstract level, use android.net.ConnectivityManager.

This is WifiManager.java:
[WifiManager class in Android 4.2.2](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.2.2_r1/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.java?av=f)

Create a new WifiManager instance. Applications will almost always want to use Context.getSystemService() to retrieve the standard Context.WIFI_SERVICE.
Parameters:
context the application context
service the Binder interface
Hide:
- hide this because it takes in a parameter of type IWifiManager, which is a system private class.

```
public WifiManager(Context context, IWifiManager service) {
    mContext = context;
    mService = service;
    init();
}
```

Comment: Thanks mr.boyfox for ur Answer.You are correct But Is WifiManager Constructor called or not and how WifiManager class is instantiated  for the call getSystemService(WIFI_SERVICE).